# Call App Script from Different Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Four spreadsheets one is Admin spreadsheet where all the code is written and other three are employee sheets.

So I want to call script in Admin sheet from Employee sheet using button. Whenever user clicks on button it copies data to Admin sheet.

I do not want code to be in each employee spreadsheet . I want all the code to be in Admin spreadsheet and give link to call the script from the employee spreadsheets.

I did not get solution after searching in google. Tried to use webapps but I think it is used only for HTML pages.

Comment: Please, refer to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) on container-bound scripts. There is no "code" in any "sheets", it is just a script project associated with a specific *document*. Take a look at the [editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) - this should get you started

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I am referring sheets as documents, there are four Excel docs. Is there any function like call function from different document.

Comment: NP. Please, don't - Google Sheets has "Spreadsheets" which have "Sheets" in them and should not be confused. That said, no there is not - you must use a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) to be able to do that and it should either be deployed as a WebApp or an API executable. Btw, WebApps as a subset of web applications are not bound to render HTML pages, this is only needed if your app needs user interaction. You can use the [`ContentService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) to communicate with the WebApp server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to create an add-on.

If you are using G Suite then the add-on could be published only to be used by users from the same domain.

An add-on it's better than a library or as publishing the script as an API because these alternatives require a script to call them.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I am going though the link provided by you. I am doing external project and working for first time in Google Sheets with the knowledge of Excel Macros.

Can you please provide more information? Like is Addon free with GSuit, I am not able to  publish as it is giving message as "you'll need to switch to a user-managed Cloud Platform project for this script.". I am not able how to switch.